# Setting FILE permissions always returns FALSE for the existing directories

Tags: java, file, unixodbc, r.java-file

I am trying to set read/write/executable permissions to an EXISTING directory in Java on UNIX platform.
The code I have -

```
File dir = new File(path);
boolean rc1 = dir.setExecutable(true, false);
boolean rc2 = dir.setReadable(true, false);
boolean rc3 = dir.setWritable(true, false);
```

All three booleans rc1,rc2,rc3 are evaluated to false.
How do I fix this?

All three booleans should evaluate to TRUE.

Comment: I used that but it says "Operation not permitted" @user16320675